# Separates session variables

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am getting an undefined:index minicart error

I have a session variable `['cart_array']` which store items in multiple array and I define them like

```
// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
```

What is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: Sometimes you use `$_SESSION["minicart"]` sometimes `$_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]` and you wrote `mini_cart`... You probably need to sort this out. And nowhere in the code you prodived you set that session variable.

Comment: @Bun accidently deleted one of the `["minicart"]` but i put it in the question now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method to return your total price rather than storing TOTAL PRICE in `$minicart`.

```
function getTotalPrice()
{
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $item)
    {
        $total += $item['price'];
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Of course replace `$item['price']` with whatever you're using to store the item prices.

Comment: u r saying i dont need `minicart`to show the overall price but i can use `cart_array` to show the number of items in the array and also the overall price? if so I will echo `cart_array` for the price and `count` to show the number of items in the array session?

Comment: No, you echo `getTotalPrice()` function. It seems the problem here is poor PHP understanding. From your previous question, you need to replace `$item['price']` in my answer above with `$price`.

Comment: u r right my understanding of php isn't the best and thanks for all your help

Comment: I ended up doing it this way but dont know if it is the right way by doing this... I deleted all the ['minicart'] from this pages so only session variable ['cart_array'] left then where i calculated the total price i did $cartTotal = $minicart = money_format("%n", (double)$cartTotal); and i put minicart in a session ` $_SESSION['smallcart']=$minicart;`